# Does $ Ev(\cos(4\pi t)u(t)) $ signal has period?

Tags: signal-analysis, periodic

According to Oppenheim's signal and systems solution book and other solutions like [this](http://cmrr-star.ucsd.edu/psiegel/Courses/Ece101_F14/ProblemSolutions/ps1/solution1.pdf)

$$
Ev(\cos(4\pi t)u(t)) = 1/2 \times ( \cos(4\pi t)u(t) + \cos(4\pi t)u(-t)) = 1/2(\cos(4\pi t)) 
$$

$$
\textrm{for }-\infty < t <  \infty
$$

is periodic and its period $1/2$.

But I think it is not equal $ 1/2(\cos 4\pi t)  $ at $ t = 0 $ so it is not periodic because at $ t = 0 $ it is equal to $ 1 $ different from other multiples of period.

I have also curious about the value of $ u(t)+u(-t) $. Is it $0$, $1$, or $2$ ?

Comment: What is the meaning of $Ev(\cdot)$?

Comment: $ Ev(f(t)) $ is even part of function f(t). $ Ev(f(t)) = 1/2(f(t) + f(-t)) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of convention. The answer depends on the definition of the step function $u(t)$. In signal processing, it is common to define $u(0)=1/2$. Under this definition, we have that $Ev(\cos(4\pi t)u(t)) = 1/2(0.5+0.5)=1/2$, so the signal is indeed periodic.

If $u(0)$ is defined as either 0 or 1, then you'd be correct and the signal wouldn't be periodic.

Comment: Could you give me a resource(book, link) that is explain this convention. I have not seen this before.

Comment: @verdery, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function , in particular the section "Zero argument".

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{d}{dt} u(t) = \delta(t) $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} u(-t) = -\delta(t) $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} ( u(t) + u(-t))=0$$
And this is true for all derivatives, 
Therefore
$$ ( u(t) + u(-t)) = 1$$ and is continuous 
for all $t$ including $t=0$ so the function in question is periodic.

Comment: I think this derivation proves that the function $u(t) + u(-t)$ has a limit as $t$ goes to $0$, but not necessarily continuous at $t=0$ and therefore does not prove the fact that $u(0)+u(-0)=1$. For the question, which looks for the periodicity of the even part of $\cos(4\pi t) u(t)$ the value at the origin is important.

Comment: If you accept that all the derivatives exist and are convergent which in this case they are zero, the function is analytic. If you don't accept that all the derivatives exist I really haven't proved anything.

Comment: You need to establish the I think part before you can move to the therefore part, so your therefore is an opinion. I have no problem with opinions but it is not a proof regardless of how many reputation points you have.

Comment: ok. The formal derivative, based on the classical calculus of analytic functions and not on Lebesgue measurable sense, of the discontinuous function $u(t)$ does not exist at the discontinuity point $t=0$ hence all of your derivations indeed is formally incorrect at the discontinuity point $t=0$... Therefore I don't know what to unprove now in fact :-)

Comment: we understand the fact that the generalized functions such as $\delta(t)$ and all of its formal derivateves and integrals in the classical sense are problematic but otherwise intuitively satisfying and quite useful for signal processing. Modern mathematics established the proper usage of improper statements involving those functions, and we all use them that way. But when it comes to prove something formally, then relying on those functions can be a weak way of doing so. In fact the funciton $u(t)$ is *undefined* at the origin and can be taken as $0$,$1$ or $0.5$ without affecting its usage.

Comment: Are you saying that the sampling theorem and periodicity of the spectrum of a sample waveform are based on "weak arguments". The first 2 equations are given (2.93) in Oppenheim and Willsky.  The derivative are all defined at x(0) because they define it as a statement and later on, define all the derivatives of delta(t). Linearity is the rest. So if not a formal theorem, an intuitively satisfying and quite useful result. My last point is that the result is consistent with the solutions book

Comment: Yes. They are based on weak arguments. The authors already admit that when they discuss the generalized functions. All operations of classical calculus such as integration and differentiations are inapplicable to those functions, unless the domain of analysis is extended to Lebesgue measure theory. So the integral cannot be a Riemann integral and the derivative is not what we considered as the limit of a quotient at the point. **but** apparetly the results are consistent. Anyway the point is your derivation says that $u(0) = 0.5$ strictly. But it may also be defined as $0$ or $1$

Comment: I'll concede that.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's check.

For a signal to be periodic with period $P$, we need:

$$
x(t) = x(t+P)
$$

for all $t$.

Here
$$ x(t) = 1/2(\cos(4\pi t))$$
and
$$ x(t+P) = 1/2(\cos(4\pi [t+P]))$$
so for such a $P$ to exist we need
$$ \cos(4\pi t) = \cos(4\pi [t+P]) = \cos(4\pi t) \cos(4\pi P) - \sin(4\pi t) \sin(4\pi P)  $$
by [applying the $\cos(A+B)$ identity.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)

We know that $\cos(2\pi) = 1$ and $\sin(2\pi) = 0$, so $P=\frac{1}{2}$ satisfies the equation for all $t$.

Comment: Peter, I think the question is not whether $\cos(4\pi t)$ is periodic, but whether the even function at $t=0$ is equal to $1/2$.

Comment: @MBaz: Ah, you may be right! Oh well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some authors say periodic signals should exist alike on positive and negative time axis.

$\cos(4\pi t)$ is periodic but, when multiplied by $u(t)$, $\cos(4\pi t)u(t)$ exists on positive axis only, so it's not periodic.

Regarding the step function, Simon Haykin states $u(0)$ is undefined for CTS due to abrupt transition from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score -1):

x(t)=1/2(cos 4 pi t u(t)+cos 4pi(-t) u(-t)) ... even function
cos(-x) =cosx but u(-t) =o as unit step function exists when t>=0
so u(-t) =0 u(t) =1 for all even values
x(t)= 1/2 cos 4 pi t ... u(t)=1 for all even values 
t= 2 pi / omega  omega = 4
t= 2pi/4 =1/2 sec [ periodic function]

if cos is replaced by sin then sin function gets 0 for even values t=0 u(t) =1 but sin 0 =0 .. x(t) =0 non periodic

Comment: Could you please edit your maths to make your answer clearer? I tried to do so to help out, e.g. `$x(t)=1/2(\cos(4 \pi t)u(t) + cos(4\pi(-t)) u(-t))$`, but when I got to '...for all even values x(t)' it got too terse for me to unambiguously understand the meaning of the rest.